# Run a specific unit test in Laravel before al other unit tests (phpunit)

Tags: laravel, testing, phpunit

I'm busy learning to unit test in Laravel and I have a question.
I want one test that has to do with authentication to run first before running other all other tests. Can this be achieved?

I have 4 test classes with a few methods so far.

Comment: In PHPUnit, every single test is run with a fresh environment, all the setting up and tearing down is done for every test, so the order does not matter. If you're trying to authenticate as part of your other tests, say for example you're testing your API and you need your tests to authenticate as a user, Laravel's testing facility has methods and helpers to let you do just that. Can you give more context to your problem? I might be able to help you better if I know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: I have some methods that will only work when the DB / authentication is set up properly, And sometimes due to my working environment the test data is gone, So I want to check in a test (before all other tests) that the test data is there. Else all my tests fail

Comment: What you'll need to do is do all of your setup in the `setUp` method of your test cases, that method is executed before each and every test is run. Similarly, the `tearDown` method is run after every one of your tests have completed. Alternatively, you could create a method that does all of your setup and call it at the beginning of each of your tests.

Comment: Your comment is an answer, If you post it as an answer i will accept it :-)

Comment: There you go :)

Comment: @Jonathon Is there a way to only do a setUp() on the first test in a class? Like a constructor

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In PHPUnit, every single test is run with a fresh environment, all the setting up and tearing down is done for every test, so the order does not matter. If you're trying to authenticate as part of your other tests, say for example you're testing your API and you need your tests to authenticate as a user, Laravel's testing facility has methods and helpers to let you do just that.

You'll need to do all of your setup in the `setUp` method of your test cases. That method is executed before each and every test is run. Similarly, the `tearDown` method is run after every one of your tests have completed:

```
public class YourTest extends TestCase
{
    protected function setUp()
    {
        // Do your setup here
    }

    protected function tearDown()
    {
        // Your cleanup here, if you're using Mockery, this 
        // is a good place to call Mockery::close();
    }

    public function testSomething()
    {
        // Your test code, you can assume that setUp has 
        // already run and you're ready to go.
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could create a method that does all of your setup and call it at the beginning of each of your tests.